# Just Cause 2 - Never get past loading screen

Tags: pc, technical-issues, just-cause-2

I bought Just Cause 2 via Steam and installed on Windows 7. My video card isn't great, but I could run the 3 test scenes at 30fps at 1280. When I played the game, it ended the first cut scene, I jumped out of the plane, it said loading, and it hung there forever. I restarted the game and the same thing happened.

I read that [some other people have the same problem, too.](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1201284) Some suggested deleting the app files, which probably just resets the video setting. That didn't help. Suggestions?

Update: I checked the minimum requirements, and I believe my PC meets them all. I have an ATI Radeon HD 3650 card, and when I lower the resolution it does just fine (30fps) on the benchmarks.

Comment: Hi Jon, welcome to Gaming, it's an honor to have you here. I hope you find a solution for your problem!

Comment: Not really of much use BUT, this is a great reason to check out OnLive's cloud gaming solution. I am by no means a hardcore gamer but I am very happy with it and they have Just Cause 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer on the [Steam forums](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1288000)

I verified the files, which caused some to be re-downloaded. After that, the game played just fine.

Answer (score 3):

Well, let's see:

The [minimum system requirements for Just Cause 2](http://store.steampowered.com/app/8190/) are:

- Windows Vista or better
- Dual Core CPU with SSE3
- 2 GB memory
- 10 GB disk space
- DX10 compatible graphics card with 256 MB of memory
- DirectX compatible sound card

The [specs for your ATI Radeon 3650](http://www.amd.com/us/products/desktop/graphics/ati-radeon-hd-3000/hd-3600/Pages/ati-radeon-hd-3600-specifications.aspx) video card:

- DirectX 10.1 support
- I'll assume your card has 256 MB of video memory, but you should check

**Did you update your video drivers to the latest version?**

http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/index.aspx

That'd be the first thing I tried. Beyond that, your video card might be too "minimum" for the game to run -- the 3650 HD is very low end, it was a budget video card in January 2008, and I would not say it has aged like a fine wine in the last 3 years.. you might consider an upgrade to the 5xxx or 6xxx series.

Comment: I've got the latest drivers. The weird thing is that it runs the benchmark scenes at 30fps no problem, and I've seen other forum posts from people with good video cards. I mostly just wanted to get this listed on gaming.stackexchange.com since looking through the random gaming forums for solutions made me want to suckerpunch a nun.

Answer (score 0):

Change your resolution and then try again! Worked for me